# Do try-except many times but raise error if one of them fails (at the end)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

So I have say 3 functions I would like to run. Each of them can fail. I would like to built `try-except` around them to:

- let as many as possible out of 3 run AND
- raise an error at the end if any of them failed. Is this possible?

The below code fails as operation D (in the middle fails) so E is never reached:

```
try:
    c = 3 + 6
    print(c)
except TypeError:
    raise TypeError("Wrong type provided in operation C")

try:
    d = 3 + '6'
    print(d)
except TypeError:
    raise TypeError("Wrong type provided in operation D")

try:
    e = 7 + 5
    print(e)
except TypeError:
    raise TypeError("Wrong type provided in operation E")
```

Comment: initialize a flag to false. inside each except turn the flag to true and don't raise an exception. at the end of the code check if the flag is true and manually raise an exception.

Answer (score 5):

```
def f1():
    print("f1")

def f2():
    raise TypeError
    print("f2")

def f3():
    print("f3")


err = None

for f in [f1, f2, f3]:
    try:
        f()
    except TypeError as e:
        # store first error
        if not err:
            err = e

if err:
    raise err
```

Output:

```
f1
f3
[...]
TypeError
```

If your functions take arguments, you can loop over

```
[(f1, f1_args, f1_kwargs), (f2, f2_args, f2_kwargs), (f3, f3_args, f3_kwargs)]
```

---

Inspired by a comment I tried to come up with a nifty context manager that sort of raises all the exceptions in a nested fashion upon exiting. Comments are welcome.

```
class ErrorCollector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.errors = []

    def exec(self, f, suppress_types=None, *args, **kwargs):
        suppress_types = tuple(suppress_types) if suppress_types else ()

        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except suppress_types as e:
            self.errors.append(e)

    def _raise_all(self, errors):
        if len(errors) == 1:
            raise errors[0]

        for e in errors:
            try:
                raise e
            except type(e):
                self._raise_all(errors[1:])

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exctype, excinst, exctb):
        if excinst is not None:
            self.errors.append(excinst)
        self._raise_all(self.errors)


def f1():
    print('f1')

def f2():
    raise TypeError('TypeError in f2')
    print('f2')

def f3():
    raise ValueError('ValueError in f3')
    print('f3')

def f4():
    raise TypeError('TypeError in f4')
    print('f4')

def f5():
    print('f5')

def f6():
    raise ZeroDivisionError('ZeroDivisionError in f6')
    print('f6')

def f7():
    print('f7')
```

Now you can use:

```
suppress = [TypeError, ValueError]

with ErrorCollector() as ec:
    for f in (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7):
        ec.exec(f, suppress)
```

with the output:

```
f1
f5
[...]
TypeError: TypeError in f2
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[...]
ValueError: ValueError in f3
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[...]
TypeError: TypeError in f4
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[...]
ZeroDivisionError: ZeroDivisionError in f6
```

Note that `f7` is not executed because the `ZeroDivisionError` was not suppressed.

Comment: This is the cleanest solution in my opinion.

Comment: @matszwecja what do you think of the context manager?

Comment: I feel like that is too big of a solution for this sort of problem. Ignoring exceptions in such a way is not something I think should be done on a bigger scale so very complex solutions don't seem necessary.

Comment: Really like the `_raise_all` method which raises all exceptions. What is the benefit of putting everything in the class with `exec, __enter__ , __exit__` methods?

Comment: @userPrimeNumber are you asking what a context manager is or why I used a context manager?

Comment: @timgeb mostly wanted to understand the concrete benefit of context manager for this use case and it has to be `exec` function or can it be any name?

Comment: @userPrimeNumber you could write a function that calls a list of functions, collects exceptions and then does something equivalent to `_raise_all` at the end. Having the context manager seems a bit more flexible because you can put additional code into the `with` block while having the freedom of calling select functions safely via the `exec` method. (The name is arbitrary, you could call it `run` or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

Other responses have provided ad-hoc handlers of various manners. An interesting alternative if this is a recurring need is to build a context manager similar to [contextlib.suppress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress), something along the lines of (untested):

```py
class Suppressor:
    def __init__(self, *to_suppress):
        self.to_suppress = to_suppress  # empty = suppress all
        self.exceptions = []

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, etype, val, _):
        if etype is not None:
            # if the exception is selected
            if not self.to_suppress or isinstance(val, self.to_suppress):
                # store and suppress it
                self.exceptions.append(val)
                return True
        # otherwise ignore
```

Usage:

```py
suppressor = Suppressor(TypeError)

with suppressor:
    c = 3 + 6
    print(c)  # 9

with suppressor:
    d = 3 + '6'  # error (suppressed)
    print(d)

with suppressor:
    e = 7 + 5
    print(e)  # 12

if suppressor.exceptions:
    # TypeError("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'")
    print(repr(suppressor.exceptions[0]))

with suppressor:
    # ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
    e = 7 + int('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple would be:

```
errors = 0 
try:
    c = 3 + 6
    print(c)
except TypeError:
    errors +=1

try:
    d = 3 + '6'
    print(d)
except TypeError:
    errors +=1

try:
    e = 7 + 5
    print(e)
except TypeError:
    errors +=1

if errors!=0:
  raise TypeError("Wrong type provided in some operation")
```

If you want to get which operation threw TypeError you can assign it in 3 different variable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the exceptions. Then, you can actually reraise them rather than building a new exception, by having access to each.

```py
exceptions = []

try:
    raise ValueError("thing 1 error")  # simulate error in first function
except ValueError as exc:
    exceptions.append(exc)

try:
    raise ValueError("thing 2 error")  # simulate error in second function
except ValueError as exc:
    exceptions.append(exc)

try:
    raise ValueError("thing 3 error")  # simulate error in third function
except ValueError as exc:
    exceptions.append(exc)
```

You can then optionally raise a new exception. Something like:

```py
if exceptions:
    raise Exception("something went wrong")
```

Which gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 21, in <module>
    raise Exception("something went wrong")
Exception: something went wrong
```

Or, you can directly access any or all of these exceptions. Something like:

```py
raise exceptions[1]
```

Which gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise exceptions[1]
  File "./main.py", line 11, in <module>
    raise ValueError("thing 2 error")  # simulate error in second function
ValueError: thing 2 error
```

Comment: Great and simple. If I implement it in this way I'll probably loop over all of the exception elements.

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that you could run many functions, and then only reraise if a subset of the exceptions met certain criteria. Like only if index errors were found but no type errors or some such. But the other methods given are a bit more simple if only knowing if any errors occurred or not.